# Inducing electric field vs Inducing magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Is it easier to induce an electric field using a changing magnetic field or the other way around?
The question is from my high school booklet, and I am pretty sure it was to be answered on an observational basis.
However, I was wondering if anyone could help me by providing a direction to think in as I wanted to approach this problem using more concrete proof/reasoning. Any valuable insights are appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electric motor converts electrical energy to magnetic fields and from that produces mechanical energy. An electric generator uses mechanical energy to move a coil through a magnetic field, which produces electrical energy.

Which one is "easier" to do? Neither. At least in a crude design, they're both the same machinery, just used in the opposite way. Any differences of efficiency or "easiness" in more sophisticated designs is a matter of engineering, not physics.

Similarly you can use a loop antenna as a receiver (converting magnetic energy to electrical) or as a transmitter (converting electrical energy to magnetic). Neither way is easier, they're just different ways to drive the same physical structure.

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to create electric field from magnetic field because there are more number of ways to do it ,

Electric flux = B.A

B is magnetic field vector

A is area vector

Here I can change the magnitude of magnetic or area vector if not I can change the orientation of both the vectors.

The only easy way I know to generate magnetic field using electric field is by passing electric current in an conductor, which is due to relativistic effect, a clear explanation is given in the link

( https://youtu.be/1TKSfAkWWN0?si=-WzNpGtB67rhycsp )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).